# Asp.net MVC - Bind excel/csv data to kendoUI grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, kendo-grid

**Scenario:**
User can upload excel file. All header columns from the excel is shown in grid with a mapping option to map it with local database.

After that, user can select number of records to import from excel.

for this, i have two `KendoUI` grids, one for column mapping and another to select records.

I have used `dynamic ExpandoObject` object to read excel file. I am able to get the excel columns and data rows in result.

```
public CustomDataTabel ReadExcelFile(string file)
{
var response = new ServiceResponse<BulkDataTable> { IsSuccess = false };

                    using (var reader = new ExcelReader(new FileInfo(file)))
                    {
                        var csvTable = reader.CreateDataTable(true);
                        if (csvTable != null)
                        {
                            var table = new CustomDataTabel ();
                            int i = 1;
                            foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in csvTable.Columns)
                            {
                                table.Columns.Add(
                                    new BulkDataColumn
                                    {
                                        Order = i,
                                        ColumnTitle = column.Caption,
                                        Key = column.ColumnName
                                    });
                                i++;
                            }

                            var j = 0;
                            for (j = 0; j < csvTable.Rows.Count; j++)
                            {
                                dynamic rowRecord = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
                                var tableRow = csvTable.Rows[j];
                                foreach (var dataColumn in table.Columns)
                                {
                                    var value = tableRow[dataColumn.Order - 1];
                                    ImpromptuInterface.Impromptu.InvokeSet(rowRecord, dataColumn.Key, value);
                                }

                                table.DataRows.Add(rowRecord);
                            }

                            response.Data = table;
                            response.IsSuccess = true;
                        }
                    }
                    return response;
}
```

I am able to bind the column mapping grid. but for rows (Data) binding there is an issue. The data (rows from excel) is a `dynamic` object with a key value data, and can't be serialize into json, thus Kendo Grid is not able to bind data.I am able to see total number of records in grid.

the logic to bind Grid is as follow:

```
var bulkDataColumn = null;
var bulkDataRow = null;

var loadColumnMapping = function (data) {
bulkDataColumn = data.BulkDataColumns;
 bulkDataRow = data.BulkDataRows;// this returns dynamic rows


 // Code to bind first grid i.e. Column mapping grid
 // I am able to bind the first grid with column details

 // Second grid (data) grid
 $("#dataGrid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: bulkDataRow,
                    pageSize: 10,
                    batch: true,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "Order",
                            fields: { // --> i don't know how to define fields, because data  and fields can be different depends on the file upload by user
                                Key: { type: "string", editable: false },
                                Value: { type: "string", editable: false },
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 10,
                editable: "incell",
                scrollable: true,
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                edit: function (e) {
                    if (!e.model.IsSelected) {
                        //revert edited cell back to `read` mode
                        this.closeCell();
                    }
                }
                ,
                pageable: true,

                columns: [
                    { field: "Key", title: "Key", width: "130px" },
                    { field: "Value", title: "Value", width: "130px" },
                ]
            });
}
```

Any ideas on how to bind `dynamic` object with kendoUI grid?
Thanks in Advance.